# Why is an "empty attribute block" not allowed?

Tags: c++, syntax

This may be the dumbest question asked today but regardless I'm going to press on:

The following derived class with overloaded operator `+=`, the base class of which overloads operator `[]` gives the following compiler error :

> empty attribute block is not allowed

I would usually write `v[0]` and `v[1]` in operator `+=` of course, however I was curious as to whether it would compile and if not, why not.

What is an attribute block? Why doesn't the compiler resolve `[0]` to the `[]` operator, returning a reference from the base class?  Simply a question of syntax or something deeper?

```
#include <array>

template<class T, int C>
struct Vec
{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef unsigned index_type;
    typedef unsigned size_type;

    std::array<T, C> v;

    template<typename ...Args>
    explicit Vec(Args&&... args) : v({{args...}}) {}
    Vec(std::array<T, C> const & o) : v(o) {}

    value_type & operator [] (index_type i)
    {           
        return v[i];
    }

    value_type const & operator [] (index_type i) const
    {
        return v[i];
    }
}; 

template<class T>
struct Vec2 : Vec<T, 2>
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    explicit Vec2(Args... args) : Vec<T, 2>(args...) {}
    Vec2(Vec2<T> const & p) : Vec<T, 2>(p.v) {}     

    Vec2<T> & operator += (Vec2<T> const & q)
    {
        [0] += q[0];
        [1] += q[1];

        return *this;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Vec2<int> a(10, 20);
    Vec2<int> b(30, 40);

    a += b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your question would be better titled as "what is an attribute block?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `operator+=` to call `operator[]`, statement like `[0]` is not a valid C++.

```
    Vec2<T> & operator += (Vec2<T> const & q)
{
    operator[](0) += q[0];
    operator[](1) += q[1];

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use operators freeform in that way. You must provide `this` explicitly, e.g. `(*this)[0]`. The error message referencing attributes is simply because `[]` can be used to denote attributes as well.